# Send concatenate sms with PDU format with iphone programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sms, pdu

is there anyway to send concatenated sms in PDU format in iPhone programmatically?
AFAIK android is able to do it.
please advice, really need this things clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS will only allow you to send a SMS via the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

This will only accept a string as it body, thus no special SMS can be send. Also the user has to press the send button to send the SMS.

Comment: so u mean, ther is no way i can do sort of thing in iPhone? sending sms without using iphone native message app